# Working with Option parameters in BIRT Reporting tool

Tags: report, birt

**I have limited knowledge about the BIRT I am still learning.**

**Case:**
I have an optional parameter in BIRT if that Parameter is **String** type I know below way to write it:

```
and ((? is null) or (file_entered_by_user_table.ss_name = ?))
```

> *But the same way doesn't work if the parameter type is **Integer**. How to write in case of Integer/Float/Date type?*

Comment: Your example is for string. Anyway, this should work in the same way for Integer. Side note: You need 2 dataset parameters with this syntax (one for each "?"). You can rewrite the query to something like "with params as (select ? as ss_name, ... from DUAL) select ... from file_entered_by_user_table f, params p where (p.ss_name is null or f.ss_name = p.ss_name)". DUAL is an Oracle specific table with exactly one row, other DB systems have similar concepts. This way you need only 1 dataset parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to give placeholder in your sql and update it on the 'beforeOpen' event of dataset.

eg. Dataset Sql:

```
 select * from dual --where_clause
```

On beforeOpen Event:

```
  if( params["parameterName"].value != null ) {

     this.queryText = this.queryText.replace("--where_clause", "where field_name = " + 
       params["parameterName"].value); 

  }else { 

       this.queryText = this.queryText.replace("--where_clause", ""); 

  }
```

This will work for any data type.